# What is the equivalent of Student's t-distribution on an interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, beta-distribution, t-distribution

I have been using Student's t-distribution as a proxy for the Gaussian distribution estimated from a limited number of points in order to calculate alpha-intervals (for instance 95% confidence intervals).

However, lately I have been working on closed intervals with distributions that are close to beta-distribution family and couldn't find any distribution that could be useful to estimate alpha-intervals while taking in account the number of samples.

What distribution would be most appropriate for such application?

Comment: Most likely the answer is the Student t distribution.  However, details matter.  Could you explain what an "alpha-interval" is and describe the data you are using to compute them?

Comment: Sure. I designate an alpha interval as the range that contains alpha percentage of the distribution. When the parameters of the distribution were estimated from experimental observations, alpha interval of the t-distribution with standard deviation equal to the standard error of mean is used to estimate the 95% confidence interval for the location of parameter of interest.

Comment: @whuber: It cannot be student T because the alpha intervals have to be bounded in [0, 1].

Comment: @NeilG That's not correct.  The applicability of the student T does not depend on the underlying distribution: it depends on the *sampling distribution of the mean*.  For any unimodal beta-like distribution and moderate sample size (perhaps more than 5), the student T will be a good choice for constructing confidence intervals of the mean. I can't say whether it would be appropriate for an "alpha interval," because we now have two conflicting characterizations of it: although the OP refers to CIs, it is described as a tolerance interval.  The student t would be inappropriate for that.

Comment: @whuber:  I don't see why what you say is true.  If you're talking about finding a posterior distribution over the parameters of the distribution, then the parameters of the Beta distribution are positive and Student T is still wrong because it won't constrain itself to the positive reals.  But I don't think that's what the asker is asking for.

Comment: @whuber: also, you can't insist on large sample sizes for this question since the whole point of this question is taking into account a poverty of data.  If he had a large sample size, he wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @NeilG That's a fine point, if you consider 5 to be large! As far as the non-negativity argument goes, it's not valid because the probability is too small to be of any concern. If that argument held, extremely few statistical tests ever could be done. BTW, since there is no indication in the question of a prior, I'm not talking about posterior distributions--only about the applicability of the Student t distribution to computing statistical intervals.

Comment: @whuber:  We should just plot the difference between the true model (as given in my answer) and your student T approximation?

Comment: @NeilG Your answer does not give a "true model," at least not according to the information in the question.  It describes a "close to beta-distribution family," not the Beta distributions themselves.

Comment: @whuber: My model is not the beta distribution; it's the beta-binomial model that I think he's describing.

Comment: @whuber: the problem is specifically that the probability of the tails of distribution overrunning outside the permitted interval is pretty significant and sometimes close to 50%, even for the confidence interval.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are interested in obtaining a confidence interval for the true mean of a distribution with bounded support (although your post does not mention the mean at any point...)

If your sample size is not tiny, then Student intervals will provide usually an excellent approximation (Central Limit Theorem, no heavy tails).

To illustrate this, we can simulate from a beta distribution with known mean, compute the t-confidence interval and check in each run if the interval contains the mean $\mu$ (which is 1/3 in the example below).

```
n <- 20 # sample size
a <- 2  # parameters of beta distribution 
b <- 4
mu <- 1/(1 + b/a) # true mean of beta distribution

set.seed(1)
out <- replicate(10000, {
  x <- rbeta(n, a, b) 
  t.test(x)$conf.int
})

mean(out[1, ] <= mu & mu <= out[2, ]) # 0.948 

par(mfrow = 1:2)
hist(x)
boxplot(x)
```

So the real coverage probability is almost exactly identical to the nominal coverage of 0.95 even if the underlying is not normal but asymmetric beta. Histogram and boxplot in the last run of the simulation are looking as follows:
[image]

If we run above simulation with tiny sample sizes, we get the following coverage probabilities:

- 0.9399 ($n = 5$)
- 0.9365 ($n = 4$)
- 0.9403 ($n = 3$)
- 0.943  ($n = 2$)

Comment: If your sample size is so big that student T looks like beta-bernoulli (the true posterior predictive), then student T also looks like normal, so why even bother taking into account the sample size :)

Comment: Do Bayesians consider sample sizes of 20 as "so big"? ;)

Comment: I guess we should just plot it.  I have no idea how close it is. :)

Comment: Unfortunately in my case I am dealing with 2-6 points at best and some classes are quite close to the limits of the interval, so my tails are definitely outside the interval bounds. Excellent guess on the formulation though, 95% confidence interval on the mean is what I usually look for.

Comment: I've added the simulation results down to $n=2$.

Comment: Why don't you compare the plot to my answer?  I don't have time right now, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is very common in the Bayesian framework.  Student's T distribution is the posterior predictive of the Gaussian model.  Given $n$ points, having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the posterior predictive distribution for subsequent points is (noncentral scaled) Student T distributed.

The exact same calculations can be done for your model, which is the Beta-binomial model.  You can find details on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution). Like the Student T, it's a three parameter distribution with density:

\begin{align}
   f(k \mid n,\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)} \frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)\Gamma(n-k+\beta)}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+\beta)} 
                         \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}.
\end{align}

This is over the domain $k\in [0,1]$. $\alpha-\frac12$ and $\beta-\frac12$ are your number of successes and failures, $n=1$ since your model is Beta-Bernoulli.

To find your $\alpha$-interval, I guess you'll have to integrate and invert the density, likely by numerical means.